# Solving quadratic inequalities $a^2-b^2+2b-1\geq0$....

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Let $a,b,p,q,r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p,q>0$. I need to find or guess some $p,q,r$ such that 
\begin{gather}
a^2-b^2+2b-1\geq0\\ 
\Downarrow\\
a^2\left[4(r-p)q-r^2\right]-b^2[4p^2-4pq]+2b\left(r(r-2p)a^2-\frac{ba^2r^2}{2}\right)+4pq\geq 0
\end{gather}
Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: These are quadratics in $b$ and solving for $b$ should give you two intervals $[b_0, b_1]$ and $[B_0, B_1]$ which $b$ must be contained in to satisfy the two inequalities. The implication simply means that $[B_0, B_1] \subset [b_0, b_1]$ then.

Comment: (You can do the same with $a$ instead of $b$, but then you get two intervals as the sign of $a^2$ in the first inequality is positive. Working with $b$ would therefore have my preference.)

Answer (score 0):

your inequality is equivalent to $$a^2-(b-1)^2\geq 0$$ using the binomial formual we obatin
$$\left(a-(b-1)\right)\left(a+b-1\right)\geq 0$$
can you finish?

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure. What about the second inequality?

Comment: what inequality do you mean?

Comment: I guess you just read the title. There are 2 inequalities in the question